# Facebook graph api Public page data

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am stuck in fetching data for a public Facebook page. I want to know which endpoint of graph api should I use to fetch the page data and how. Will anybody please help. I have tried to make a get request for public page content access

Comment: I do not see any code? Please show us what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you don't need a special endpoint, you just have to use the id of the page when making the call, in the same way you do with a user profile.

but in order to make a call to a public page, you need your app to be [reviewed and approved by the Facebook team](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review).

Comment: Well m developing a Web app in which data from multiple pages will be fetched. Will they review my app each time or just once?

Comment: Also if you can tell how do I send them a request to review my app. That would be helpful. 

Comment: only once, I add the link of the review instructions in the main answer